# How do I get LOAD_CLASSDEREF instruction after dis.dis?

Tags: python, disassembly

What function / class should I write to get LOAD_CLASSDEREF as a bytecode instruction?

I have been able to find functions / classes that result in LOAD_BUILD_CLASS, LOAD_CONST, LOAD_GLOBAL, LOAD_FAST, LOAD_ATTR, LOAD_DEREF, LOAD_NAME, bytecode, but what function / class would give LOAD_CLOSURE and LOAD_CLASSDEREF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOAD_CLASSDEREF` is used for when a class body accesses a closure variable, so have a class body access a closure variable:

```
def foo():
    x = 3
    class Bar:
        print(x)
```

The code object for `Bar` will then use `LOAD_CLASSDEREF`. Depending on your Python version, you may have to dig the code object out of `foo.__code__.co_consts` and call `dis.dis` on that code object directly to see the opcode in the `dis.dis` output.

You can also see a `LOAD_CLOSURE` in the bytecode for `foo`.